# Hangfire como utilizar

Tags: aplicação-web, hangfire

Desculpem se for uma pergunta muito idiota, mas gostaria de saber o que é mais "correto" utilizar o hangfire em um projeto a parte, como api por exemplo, ou posso tranquilamente utilizar dentro do meu projeto web? Tem algum problema em implementar no meu projeto diretamente?